# How to unblock Microsoft employee smart card PIN?

Tags: windows-7, smartcard

I can't use my smart card any more. When using it to unlock my PC, I get "smart card is blocked", and in other scenarios I am told my PIN has been guessed incorrectly too many times.

I don't recall guessing incorrectly, but anyway I need to unblock my smart card. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing what kind of card you're using: often resetting is not possible. Once blocked, *all* access to the smart card is blocked, including any access that might be used to change the PIN.

So I guess you need to find a way to register/associate another card with the same computer.

(Providing more details on your system may help though.)

Comment: Thanks.  +1 since I didn't even know that the type of card mattered.

Comment: I've added to the Q title the type of card.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Microsoft employee smart cards can be unblocked even off the corporate network.  Employees should contact MSIT for help.